# Get all managers for a user - company hierarchy structure

Tags: flow, api, powerapp, azure-ad-graph-api

How to get a list of all managers for a users?

Example:

- User A reports to user B
- User B reports to user C
- User C reports to user D (CEO) and top of the hierarchy.

---

- By giving user A I should get: [B,C,D]
- By giving user B I should get:[C,D]
- By giving user D I should get: []

---

Any API's or existing connectors that I can use to achieve that?

The hierarchy is already in place in AD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a single API call that will walk up the hierarchy for you.  But both **Power Automate** and the [**Graph API**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-manager?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) can retrieve a given user's Manager.  Screenshot of the **Get Manager** action in Power Automate under the **O365 Users** category below:

[image]

To walk up the hierarchy, start by `Initialize a variable` of type string named something like `lookupManager` and set its initial value to be the current/chosen/selected user.  Then `Initialize a variable` of type Arrary named something like `managerChain`.  Then create a `Do until` loop set to run until `lookupManager` is null.  Inside that loop, execute the **Get Manager** with the `lookupManager` as the input.  If that action returns Success, then set `foundManager` to the newly found manager **and also** append it to your `managerChain`.  In a parallel branch if the **Get Manager** action failed, then set `foundManager` to `null` which will cause the loop to stop.

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I ended up doing.